# Groupby for diffrent dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that has individual level data (so each row is one individual) for cancer patients from 2006 to 2016 for 54 counties in California. I generated a cancer count (of 1) for each row to eventually sum up the cancer incidences by county and year for each demographics. I generated dummy variables for my categorical variables, but don't know how to proceed from there.I have tried to grouby, but it's only giving me a combination of all the demographics (for example, I want all male patients in 2008 in county_x but I get white male patients that are in the age range_x instead) This is my dataset right now:

| ID # | Year | County | Sex_1 | Race_2 | Race_3 | age_range_2 | age_range_3 | age_range_4 | cancer_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | 2008 | CC | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 325 | 2008 | CC | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 326 | 2010 | AL | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 327 | 2015 | Y | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 328 | 2008 | AL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

My desired dataset would have a cancer count by sex, race, age_ranges. Not an intersection of all, but an overall value for each demographic by county and year.Something like this:

| Year | County | Sex_1 | Race_2 | Race_3 | age_range_2 | age_range_3 | age_range_4 | cancer_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | CC | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 560 |
| 2008 | CC | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 678 |
| 2008 | CC | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 189 |
| 2008 | CC | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 543 |

I want to feed my desired output into a regression model. How can I achieve this?

Here is the groupby I tried:

```
cancer_pivot=cancer_df.groupby(["Year","County","Sex","Race","age_range"]).count().reset_index()
cancer_pivot= pd.get_dummies(cancer_pivot, columns=['Sex',"Race","age_range"],drop_first=True)
```

Comment: Please show the code you had for your groupby()

Comment: I edited the question to add the groupby code.